# Cannot t read properties of unknown reading ('cache')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been trying to make a welcome embed for a Discord.js bot. My problem is, that I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
```

If I modify `guild` to `guilds` then I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

I'm trying to display the amount of members in the guild (server). However, this error is preventing me. I've tried googling but I am unable to find any solutions, so I came here. I am using Discord.js v13.6 (the latest version).

The code is supposed to show an **embed**, when a member joins the guild.
Here, of course, is my code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
   name: 'guildMemberAdd',
   once: false,
   execute(member) {
       console.log('New member joined')
       const WelcomeChannel = '941373101277589564'
       const guild =  member.guilds.cache.get('940180806696058910')
       const channel = member.guilds.channels.cache.get(WelcomeChannel)
       let welcomeEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`Welcome <@${member.user.id}> to the **Monocle Games** Discord server.\n Member Count: ${guild.memberCount} `)
            .setTimestamp()

        welcomeEmbed.setAuthor({
            name: '**WELCOME**',
            iconURL: member.user.avatarURL()
        })
        channel.send({embeds: [welcomeEmbed]})
   }
}
```

It is part of an event handler, however that is not related to the problem. My first thought was that the way I was getting the guild was outdated, however, I do believe this is the latest version, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*If I modify `guild` to `guilds` then I get this error*" - then why do you modify it? There's no such thing as `GuildMember#guilds`, what do you expect to get from that?

Comment: You should be using `member.client.guilds` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member has `guild` property:

```js
const guild = member.guild
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(WelcomeChannel)
```